# Having user input name the new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, input

I'm wondering how I can get what was entered in by the user in Activity1 to be the title of Activity 2 when launched.

This is Activity1's createEvent button. Notice that it pulls from the eventNamebox. This is where the user will input what the event will be called. I want that name to be then sent to the new activity (Activity2) and the name be that user input.

```
public void createEvent(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Launch.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventNameBox);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

As for Activity2, this is what I have

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra(NewInputActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Also would it be easier if there are multiple entries on activity1 to have them stored in an array and then send the whole array to activity 2 or can I send them individually (by adding multiple putExtra's?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

[`setTitle(name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

to change the title of the activity.
As for the second question if the extras are related you can send them as a single extra using  [`putExtra (String name, String[] value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). If the values are unrelated you could send them using different extras